# reference suggestion in latex windows (multi-file structure)

Tags: latex, reference

There is some editor of latex that managed the labels for a multifile document?.
I tried with TexMaker and LED, and they offers me suggestions about the labels present in the actual document and in the "Master" document but not the labels present in other files of the structure. I made a script to find those other labels but it will be real good that the suggestions covers all the file structure automatically. 
Finally i tried with Vim and Latex-Suite, this extension has that posibility but i have problem configuring the grep program despite having followed all the instructions found in their website and in the help files, :(.

the structure is like this:
document.tex
mystyle.sty
mybibliography.bib
tex/file1.tex
tex/file2.tex
tex/...
img/img1.png
img/img2.png
.
.
.

Answer (score 3):

The [Reftex package for Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/reftex.html) (part of Auctex), manages multifile documents.

Comment: +1 on Auctex, best LaTeX env. I know (providing, of course, that you're an Emacs user)

Comment: i installed emacs, and auctex, and i'm learning a little every day, for this problem in specific i add to the final of every document the information about the master document, the problem is that im still can't see suggestion about the other files, can you give a hint of how to do it?

Comment: OMG it works, C-c ) then i select "section"for the type, and then r for rescan, magically every label of my all thesis appear, :)